# How to filter firebase data to display on recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: table with true in done node]

[image: table with false in done node]

I have a firebase database with a table Trips which i created to record all the trips which user make. In trips database i have a node called done which return the boolean value true if the trip is done or false if trip is canceled or not done.

I want to display all data in recyclerview from a trip database  which ridermodel node equal to current user and  done node equals to true(boolean). But when i populate data in a recyclerview i have managed to populate all the data for current user using orderByChild , but when i try to filter data to get only data with true value in done node i cant and the result i get all the data including data which is false in done node.

```
   private void loadTripplannerList() {
    
    String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    List<TripPlannerModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference tripRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.Trip);
    query = tripRef.orderByChild("rider").equalTo(user);

    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TripPlannerModel>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query, TripPlannerModel.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TripPlannerModel, CompletedTripAdapter>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CompletedTripAdapter holder, int position,
                                        @NonNull final TripPlannerModel model) {

            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                        for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            Boolean isDone = itemSnapshot.child("done").getValue(Boolean.class);
                            if (isDone.equals(true)){

                            compositeDisposable.add(iGoogleAPI.getDirections("driving",
                                    "less_driving",
                                    model.getOrigin(), model.getDestination(),
                                    getString(R.string.google_api_key))
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                    .subscribe(returnResult -> {

                                        try {

                                            //parse json
                                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(returnResult);
                                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                            JSONArray legs = object.getJSONArray("legs");
                                            JSONObject legObjects = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                                            String start_address = legObjects.getString("start_address");

                                            holder.txt_pickup.setText(Common.formatAdress(start_address));

                                        } catch (Exception e) {

                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }));

                            TripPlannerModel model = itemSnapshot.getValue(TripPlannerModel.class);
                            tempList.add(model);

                        }
                                try {

                                    marker_me = "color:holo_red|" + model.getOrigin();
                                    // marker_dest = "color:orange|label:7|San Francisco,USA";
                                    key = getString(R.string.google_api_key);
                                    marker_me = URLEncoder.encode(marker_me, "UTF-8");

                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                //String STATIC_MAP_API_ENDPOINT = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=" +width+ "x300&path=" + path + "&markers=" + marker_me + "&markers=" + marker_dest + "&key=" + key;

                                String STATIC_MAP_API_ENDPOINT = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=" + width / 2 + "x300&markers=" + marker_me + "&zoom=14&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off&key=" + key;
                                ;

                                Long timeStamp = model.getComplete_time();

                                holder.txt_trip_date.setText(UserUtils.getDate(timeStamp));
                                Picasso.get()
                                        .load(STATIC_MAP_API_ENDPOINT)
                                        .into(holder.img_map);

                                holder.txt_destination.setText(model.getDestinationString());

                                holder.txt_trip_status.setText(R.string.status_complete);

                                holder.setItemClickListerner(new IRecyclerClickListerner() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClickListerner(View view, int pos) {
                                        //
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), adapter.getRef(position).getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TripHistorySinglePage.class);

                                        intent.putExtra("destination", getItem(position).getDestinationString());
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


        });

    }
```

Comment: Please help to show the content rather than in images

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean can you elaborate a little please@Ashok

Comment: Please post the content which is there in the image you've shared. if you post images it'll be hard for search engine and also will be hard for us to replicate

Comment: It looks like you're trying to filter on two properties: `rider` and `done`. Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For your case you could for example create a property `"rider_done": "uidOfRider_true"`, and order/filter on that. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase